# C: Creating a AVL balanced Tree

Tags: c, avl-tree, tree-balancing

I'm trying to write a code to create a AVL balanced binary tree. 
The purpose is that the subtree shall be rotate to keep the (AVL) balance each time a new node is inserted.

(All values in the left subtree of a node must be smaller than this node value;
All values in the right subtree of a node must be higher than this node value)

The code I just wrote work for numbers inserted in a specific order but not in others.
For example, the following inputs work fine:

```
10 7 14 12 15 3 0 

16 8 20 14 23 0
```

This one will not:

```
10 7 3 15 12 14 0 

10 7 5 14 13 0
```

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {false, true} Boolean;
typedef enum {minus = -1, zero, plus} balance;

typedef struct nohh {
    int info;
    balance bal;
    struct nohh *left;
    struct nohh *right;
} nohh, *noh;

void PrintTree(noh p);
Boolean Insert(noh *p, int x, Boolean *alt);
void RotateLL(noh p, noh p1);
void RotateLR(noh p, noh p1);
void RotateRR(noh p, noh p1);
void RotateRL(noh p, noh p1);

int main(){
    noh p = NULL;
    int x;
    Boolean check = false, *bol = &check;

    printf("int number ('0' to exit): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    do{
        check = Insert(&p, x, bol);
        printf("check = %d\n", check);

        printf("int number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }while(x != 0);

    PrintTree(p);

    return 0;
}

void PrintTree(noh p){
    printf("%d >> bal = %d\n", p->info, p->bal);
    if(p->left != NULL)
        PrintTree(p->left);
    if(p->right != NULL)
        PrintTree(p->right);
}

Boolean Insert(noh *p, int x, Boolean *alt){
    int info;

    if((*p)==NULL){
        *p = malloc(sizeof(nohh));
        (*p)->left = (*p)->right = NULL;
        (*p)->info = x;
        (*p)->bal = zero;
        *alt = true;
        return true;
    } else { /* if p isnt pointing to NULL */
        info = (*p)->info;
        if(x == info)
            return false;
        else if(x < info){ /* follow left */
            Boolean res = Insert(&(*p)->left, x, alt);
            if(!res)
                return false;
            if(*alt){ /* height increase */
                noh p1;
                switch((*p)->bal){
                case plus:
                    (*p)->bal = zero; *alt = false;
                    break;
                case zero:
                    (*p)->bal = minus; 
                    break;
                case minus: /* -1 -1 = -2 => not balanced!! */
                    p1 = (*p)->left;
                    if(p1->bal == minus){
                        /* Rotation LL */
                        RotateLL(*p, p1);
                        *alt = true;
                    } else if(p1->bal == plus){
                        /* Rotation LR */
                        RotateLR(*p, p1);
                        *alt = true;
                    } else {
                        /* Rotation LL */
                        RotateLL(*p, p1);
                        *alt = false;
                    }
                    p1->bal = zero; *alt = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else { /* follow right */
            Boolean res = Insert(&(*p)->right, x, alt);
            if(!res)
                return false;
            if(*alt){ /* height increase */
                noh p1;
                switch((*p)->bal){
                case minus:
                    (*p)->bal = zero; *alt = false;
                    break;
                case zero:
                    (*p)->bal = plus; 
                    break;
                case plus: /* 1 +1 = 2 => Not balanced! */
                    p1 = (*p)->right;
                    if(p1->bal == plus){
                        /* Rotation RR */
                        RotateRR(*p, p1);
                        *alt = true;
                    } else if(p1->bal == minus){
                        /* Rotation RL */
                        RotateRL(*p, p1);
                        *alt = true;
                    } else {
                        /* Rotation RR */
                        RotateRR(*p, p1);
                        *alt = false;
                    }
                    p1->bal = zero; *alt = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}

void RotateLL(noh p, noh p1){
    noh p2, aux;

    p2 = p1->left;

    aux = p;
    p = p1;
    p->right = aux;

    aux->left = aux->right = NULL;
    aux->bal = p2->bal = p->bal = zero;
}

void RotateLR(noh p, noh p1){
    noh p2, aux;
    aux = p;
    p2 = p1->right;

    p = p2;
    p2->left = p1;
    p2->right = aux;

    aux->left = aux->right = NULL;
    p1->left = p1->right = NULL;
    aux->bal = p1->bal = p->bal = zero;
}

void RotateRR(noh p, noh p1){
    noh p2, aux;

    p2 = p1->right;

    aux = p;
    p = p1;
    p->left = aux;

    aux->left = aux->right = NULL;
    aux->bal = p2->bal = p->bal = zero;
}

void RotateRL(noh p, noh p1){
    noh p2, aux;
    aux = p;
    p2 = p1->left;

    p = p2;
    p2->right = p1;
    p2->left = aux;

    aux->left = aux->right = NULL;
    p1->left = p1->right = NULL;

    aux->bal = p1->bal = p->bal = zero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementations of RotateLL/LR/RL/RR are flawed — they adjust pointers correctly between the nodes involved in the rotation, but they don't change the pointer to the old root node. This is causing nodes to be lost when rotations occur.

You'll see what's going on if you insert a call to `PrintTree()` inside the loop in `main()`. For instance:

```
int number ('0' to exit): 1
check = 1
1 >> bal = 0
int number: 2
check = 1
1 >> bal = 1
2 >> bal = 0
int number: 3
check = 1
1 >> bal = 0
```

It'll probably be easiest to have each of the Rotate functions return a pointer to the new root node, and  update pointers appropriately in `Insert()`. Remember, there are some situations where `Insert()` will need to update `*p` to reflect the fact that the root node has moved!

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff . That seems to solve this part of the problem.
I cant keep the tree balanced yet. I'll put the new code below.